# How do i know which action / filters are called when i call get_option()

Tags: actions, options

I need to know which action / filters are called when i do a `get_option()` call, how can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go down the rabbit hole... http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3.2/wp-includes/functions.php#L306